# bash: Iterating over members of a JSON array selected by index

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

I'm using `jq` to parse a JSON file, extracting each JSON array in a series into a shell array.

My current code looks like the following:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#nvars[@]}; i++)); do
    v1=($(cat $INPUT | jq '."config"[i]."var1"[]'))
    echo $v1
done
```

error message:

```
error: i is not defined
```

I also replaced

```
v1=($(cat $INPUT | jq '."config"[i]."var1"[]'))
```

with

```
v1=($(cat $INPUT | jq '."config"[$i]."var1"[]'))
```

still not working. Any idea? Any help is appreciated!

---

Edit: Sample Input Data

```
{
    "config-vars":[
        {
            "var1":["v1","v2"],
            "var2":""
        },
        {
            "var1":["v3",""],
            "var2":"v4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: There are some very detailed answers here.  My preferred solution, though its relevance depends on the control-flow of your script:  `each_obj() {  
    local cmd="$1" json_arr="$2" len i;  
    len=$(jq 'length' <(echo "$json_arr"));  
    for (( i=0; i<len; i+=1 )); do  
        $cmd "$(jq ".[$i]" <(echo "$json_arr"))";  
    done;  
}`

Comment: @Shane, I would suggest inverting that a bit: `json_arr="$1"; shift`, and then you can use `"$@"` to run a command consisting of all other arguments without risking the issues in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 via use of `$cmd`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a fair bit of room for improvement. Let's start here:

```
v1=($(cat $INPUT | jq '."config"[$i]."var1"[]'))
```

...first, you don't actually need to use `cat`; it's slowing your performance, because it forces `jq` to read from a pipe rather than from your input file directly. Just running `jq <"$INPUT"` would be more robust (or, better, `<"$input"`, to avoid using all-uppercase names, which are reserved by convention for shell builtins and environment variables).

Second, you need to quote all variable expansions, including the expansion of the input file's name -- otherwise, you'll get bugs whenever your filename contains spaces.

Third, `array=( $(stuff) )` splits the output of `stuff` on *all characters in IFS*, and expands the results of that splitting as a series of glob expressions (so if the output contains `*.txt`, and you're running this script in a directory that contains text files, you get the names of those files in your result array). Splitting on newlines only would mean you could correctly parse multi-word strings, and disabling glob expansion is necessary before you can use this technique reliably in the presence of glob characters. One way to do this is to set `IFS=$'\n'` and run `set -h` before running this command; another is to redirect the output of your command into a `while read` loop (shown below).

Fourth, string substitution into code is bad practice in any language -- that way lies (local equivalents to) [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/), allowing someone who's supposed to be able to only change the data passed into your process to provide content which is processed as executable code (albeit, in this case, as a `jq` script, which is less dangerous than arbitrary code execution in a more full-featured language; still, this can allow extra data to be added to the output).

Next, once you're getting `jq` to emit newline-separated content, you don't need to read it into an array at all: You can iterate over the content as it's written from `jq` and read into your shell, thus preventing the shell from needing to allocate memory to buffer that content:

```
while IFS= read -r; do
  echo "read content from jq: $REPLY"
done < <(jq -r --arg i "$i" '.config[$i | tonumber].var1[]' <"$input")
```

Finally -- let's say you *do* want to work with an array. There are two ways to do this that avoid pitfalls. One is to set `IFS` explicitly and disable glob expansion before the assignment:

```
IFS=$'\n' # split only on newlines
set -f
result=( $(jq -r ... <"$input") )
```

The other is to assign to your array with a loop:

```
result=( )
while IFS= read -r; do
  result+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(jq -r ... <"$input")
```

...or, as suggested by @JohnKugelman, to use `read -a` to read the whole array in one operation:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a result < <(jq -r ... <"$input")
```

Comment: Hello @CharlesDuffy , I tried `nvars=($(jq --arg i "$i" '."config-vars"[$i]."var1"[]' "$INPUT"))` but getting error: `jq: error: Cannot index array with string`. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @odieatla, what's the value of `i` you're passing?

Comment: @odieatla, ...also, it would be very helpful if your question contained sample data in the same format as what your query needs to work with.

Comment: @odieatla, ...also, using `-r` (`--raw-output`) is a good idea; otherwise, jq's output will contain characters like quotes that the shell won't correctly parse during word-splitting, but will instead treat as literal data.

Comment: Great answer. Perhaps the loop could be eliminated by using `read -a`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman, hmm; I'd expect `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a result` to work off the top of my head, but let me actually test it...

Comment: @JohnKugelman, ...tested and amended into the answer; thanks!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , i just the index of the array. should be an integer. added sample data to the question. Thank you!

Comment: @odieatla, heh -- looks like `jq` assumes that all input via `--arg` is a string; that does indeed pose a problem for trying to use `--arg` here. I'm looking into the availability of workarounds.

Comment: @odieatla, found a solution -- documented in https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/605, and now amended in my answer; using `$i | tonumber` inside the jq query will cast the value to an integer.

Comment: @odieatla, thus: `jq -r --arg i 1 '.["config-vars"][$i | tonumber].var1[]' <test.json` works with the data you provided in your question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , the `tonumber` works! Thanks for saving my day!

Comment: @odieatla... btw, it turns out that I made a mistake on the `read -a` form in the answers (the one in the comments was fine); apologies if you were trying to use that, now corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Variables aren't interpolated inside single quotes. Use double quotes instead, and remove the existing quotes.

```
v1=($(cat $INPUT | jq ".config[$i].var1[]"))
```

Or use the `--arg` option and then you can stick with single quotes.

```
v1=($(cat $INPUT | jq --arg i "$i" '.config[$i].var1[]'))
```

You could also fix the useless use of cat:

```
v1=($(jq ".config[$i].var1[]" "$INPUT"))
```

Also, see @CharlesDuffy's answer for a great, detailed explanation of why assigning to array like this is unsafe.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more question, what should I do if I have 'config-vars' instead of 'config'? I suppose that's the reason why single quote was used in the first place. Thanks very much!

Comment: Try: `.[\"config-vars\"][$i]`.

Comment: This isn't a bad approach, but `jq` can be told to be more helpful -- it has a mode where output is newline-delimited, allowing more robust operation than splitting on any IFS character.

Comment: Props for amending to suggest use of `--arg`; I was just commenting on that, and saw it was in.

Comment: Another gotcha here -- if `jq` emits `*`, it'll be replaced with a list of filenames in the local directory in the resulting array.

Comment: How can i get multiple values here in to variables like read v1 v2=($(jq ".config[$i].var1[] .confg[$i].var2" "$INPUT"))

Answer (score 2):

If you have already stored the result of some JSON into a variable called $MY_VAR:

```
while IFS= read -r; do
  echo "$REPLY"
done < <(echo "$MY_VAR" | jq -r '.[]')
```

Answer (score 1):

`jq` is capable of extracting the structure in one go, so the entire loop is superfluous.  If the input JSON contains more records than you have values in `nvars`, use the index to chop.

```
jq -r '."config-vars"[]."var1"' "$INPUT" |
head -n "${#nvars[@]}"  # If you need just the #nvars first values
```