# Loop through JSON object using jq

Tags: bash, iteration, jq

This is what my JSON array of objects looks like:

```
[
    {
        "Description": "Description 1",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 1",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 1"
    },
    {
        "Description": "Description 2",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 2",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 2"
    },
    {
        "Description": "Description 3",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 3",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 3"
    },
    {
        "Description": "Description 4",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 4",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 4"
    },
    {
        "Description": "Description 5",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 5",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 5"
    },
    {
        "Description": "Description 6",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 6",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 6"
    }
]
```

How do i iterate over this using jq so that i can use the values of OutputKey and OutputValue in other commands?

Comment: @tripleee, as author of the accepted answer on that other question, I chose to answer this one separately because, rereading that answer, I didn't think it was particularly useful/applicable here -- it spent too much time "in the weeds" of what the OP there was doing wrong, and not enough providing a general and applicable good practice. Indeed, it assumes that the OP already knows jq, and focuses strictly on the bash end -- not providing any guidance on how to actually iterate through the array at all.

Comment: @tripleee, ...honestly, if there's room to close one as a duplicate of the other, I'd almost be tempted to close that one as a duplicate of this, as the answer here is more likely to be useful to others (and the question here is asked in a manner conducive to such an answer, without a prior implementation that needs a bunch of guidance/correction).

Comment: @tripleee, ...I've updated the other question to have a title that better reflects its (not-particularly-generalizable) contents.

Comment: (Context for others reading: This was temporarily closed as a duplicate of the question now known as [bash: Iterating over members of a JSON array selected by index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993448/bash-iterating-over-members-of-a-json-array-selected-by-index), but previously titled "Shellscript: loop through a JSON array" -- not a particularly accurate name, inasmuch as the OP there was trying to iterate over *several* JSON arrays, and their immediate bug was with respect to how they selected an array to iterate over on any given invocation).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your always helpful and contructive work here; absolutely no objections from me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming your content is coming from `in.json`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in (""|[123].*) echo "Bash 4.0 or newer required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A values=( ) descriptions=( )

while IFS= read -r description &&
      IFS= read -r key &&
      IFS= read -r value; do
  values[$key]=$value
  descriptions[$key]=$description
  echo "Read key $key, with value $value and description $description" >&2
done < <(jq -r '.[] | (.Description, .OutputKey, .OutputValue)' <in.json)
```

Given your input, this emits the following to stderr:

```
Read key OutputKey 1, with value OutputValue 1 and description Description 1
Read key OutputKey 2, with value OutputValue 2 and description Description 2
Read key OutputKey 3, with value OutputValue 3 and description Description 3
Read key OutputKey 4, with value OutputValue 4 and description Description 4
Read key OutputKey 5, with value OutputValue 5 and description Description 5
Read key OutputKey 6, with value OutputValue 6 and description Description 6
```

Moreover, after this code is run, you can then execute:

```
key_to_look_up="OutputKey 1"
echo "${values[$key_to_look_up]}"
echo "${descriptions[$key_to_look_up]}"
```

...and get as output:

```
OutputValue 1
Description 1
```

Comment: Note that  '.[] | [.Description, .OutputKey, .OutputValue] | .[]' can be simplified to:  '.[] | (.Description, .OutputKey, .OutputValue)', and even the parens can be dropped in this particular case.

Comment: Good points, thank you! I think the parens add clarity, so I'll keep them in, but you've actually helped me understand jq's model a little better.

Comment: (And getting rid of the unnecessary intermediate arrays is an improvement in every regard -- both more readable, and less processing overhead; thank you again).

Comment: This script doesn't run when copy-pasta'd into foo.sh. *******

foo.sh: line 3: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
foo.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
foo.sh: line 11: `done < <(jq -r '.[] | (.Description, .OutputKey, .OutputValue)' <in.json)' **********

Any chance for a full working script?

Comment: @KennSebesta, you need to run it with a compatible shell -- bash 4.0 or later (MacOS ships with 3.2, but you can install a modern release with macports or Homebrew). And make sure you actually invoke it as `bash` -- using `sh` puts the shell in compatibility mode, even if it's a link to the `bash` executable.

Comment: @KennSebesta, ...that said, I've added a shebang line and a version check to the top of the script, making it standalone as you request. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks, thats perfect, and taught me something to boot.

Comment: what would be the change required in above code if the json in is a vaiable and not in file.I am no shell expert but I tried `done < < $(echo ${MY_VAR} | jq '.[] | .[]  | (.SnapshotId, .StartTime)')`. but this does not seem to work

Comment: @shshnk You want something more like `done < <(jq '.[][] | (.SnapshotId, .StartTime)' <<<"$MY_VAR")`, assuming the extra `[]` is correct for your data; `<(...)` is process substitution syntax, which generates a filename that can be redirected from to refer to a process's output, whereas the first `<` redirects from that file. And always quote your variable expansions -- see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm afraid your question isn't very clear.  If you want to produce the values for consumption by some tool or application other than jq, then it would be helpful to know what that tool expects.  If you want to use the values in jq itself, then you could use `map` or `reduce`; alternatively, you could use a filter having the form: `.[] | ...` or `[.[] ...]`, where the `...` is some jq code that accesses the values of interest, e.g.

   ```
   [.[] | [.OutputKey, .OutputValue] ]
   ```
2. If you want to perform some reduction operation, then you will probably want to use the form: `reduce .[] as $x (_; _)`
3. There are other alternatives, depending on what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I have fixed the JSON. I am trying to run a for loop on this array and grab the values that i can pass to other functions i am calling in the for loop. The values i am looking to get are by using OutputKey.