# Improve `jq | @base64` speed

Tags: bash, jq

**Note:** This is a simplified version of a large script.

The real scripts recursively searches for a server to ssh to, each `.g[]` (group) can contain more `groups` and eventualy will contain a `.s` (server) object which holds IP/name/user/etc...

After showing the first groups (which takes too long) the user is asked which group he wants to 'enter' or which server he wants to connect to. (Servers omitted to simplify)

---

Consider the following JSON file;

```
{
    "g": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Group - 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Group - 2"
        },
        ...
        {
            "id": "10",
            "name": "Group - 10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), I'm showing the user each 'option' presented in the `.g[]` array.

Based on [this](https://starkandwayne.com/blog/bash-for-loop-over-json-array-using-jq/) post, I'm using the following `for-loop` to iterate of the 'options';

```sh
for row in $(jq -r '.g[] | @base64' <<< $raw); do
    echo -e "${prefix}    $(_jq $row '.id')${hk}  $(_jq $row '.name')"
done
```

---

**Problem**: The script needs ~`0.6` seconds to show me the first 10 entries;

```
$ time ./script
./script  0.61s user 0.09s system 101% cpu 0.685 total
```

**Question**: How to improve the speed of the script?

---

Some failed attempts;

- Tried implementing the following `loop-logic` but unfortunately could not make it work

  - [Loop through JSON object using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736840/loop-through-json-object-using-jq)
- Removing `| @base64` and `base64 --decode` causes the loop to show each literal row

---

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Statics
_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )/"
red=`tput setaf 1`; green=`tput setaf 2`; yellow=`tput setaf 3`; blue=`tput setaf 4`; magenta=`tput setaf 5`; cyan=`tput setaf 6`; bow=`tput setaf 0;tput setab 7`; reset=`tput sgr0`; hk="${blue})${reset}"; undl=`tput smul`; bold=`tput bold`;

# getopts
P_DEBUG=false
while getopts "q: d" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        d) P_DEBUG=true ;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

#
#       _jq
#       Decodes and search for json key/value
#       $1 --> json
#       $2 --> key
#
function _jq() {
    echo ${1} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${2}
}

# Validate & Read JSON
jq -e type ./json.json >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo -e 'Invalid JSON!'
raw=`jq . ./json.json`

# Search for server
reached_end=false
while [[ $reached_end == false ]]; do

    # Show id & name of each group
    for row in $(jq -r '.g[] | @base64' <<< $raw); do
        echo -e "${prefix}    $(_jq $row '.id')${hk}  $(_jq $row '.name')"
    done

    # Debug
    exit 22
done
```

Comment: `for row in $(` do not do that, parse each line as it is outputted by the utility. If you are looking for speed, do not use shell loops. I think all you are doing could be just scripted in `jq`. Please post the output you want to show to the user.

Comment: Why are you using `base64` at all? Are you just trying to output the data in a table?

Comment: I've added some additional info. If I understand correctly, I should use build-in `jq` functions to show te user the 'options' and after asking for user input, using `jq` again instead of bash `while`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That approach is way more complex than is really needed. Does this do what you wanted?

```
< json.json jq --arg prefix "${prefix}" --arg hk "${hk}" -r \
  '.g[] | "\($prefix)    \(.id) \($hk)  \(.name)"'
```

This replaces the `for` loop entirely with a single `jq` call, using jq to do the string formatting instead of `echo`, eliminating the base64 encoding and decoding, and eliminating four subprocess calls per row.

Comment: Awesome! I see now that I have to use `jq` more often instead of wanting to do it myself with bash.

Comment: @0stone0 glad to help. It's not really that one tool is better than the other, just that you need to manage complexity. Since jq has the better JSON handling, *and* it can do the rest of what you need, the best way to reduce data-flow complexity is to keep it all in jq :)